# Multiple rows inserted when using INSERT statement in PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

I need to upload 3 details which are: **Description, Number, and Image**

The query does succeed, however I am having 2 different rows instead of a single row.

Please refer to the image: [image: proverbs]

For some reason the first row is skipping the `../uploads/` path, and applied on the bottom row as shown above.

Kindly find my `PHP` code, maybe there's something which I'm missing out.

```
    <?php
    $prov = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    require_once("connection.php");
    $connection = connectToMySQL();
    $proverbDescription = $prov->proverbDescription;
    $proverbNumber = $prov->proverbNumber;  
    $imgPath = $prov->imgPath;
    $target_dir = "../uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imgPath"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["imgPath"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["imgPath"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgPath"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imgPath"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
        echo($proverbDescription);
        echo($proverbNumber);
        echo($imgPath);
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_proverb (proverbDescription, proverbNumber, imgPath) VALUES ('$proverbDescription', '$proverbNumber', '$target_file')";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
             or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0){
                $success = true;
        }else{
                $success = false;
        }
?>
```

Thanks and Regards,
Hurka

Comment: Whatever calls this script, is calling it twice.

Comment: My guess is you're using AJAX to submit the form, but you're not preventing the default form submission. Since the default form method doesn't send JSON, you get empty values in `$prov`.

Comment: @Barmar what you're saying may be correct. I am using `HTML` and passing through `AngularJS`. This is my `HTML Form ` Submission: `<form id="demo" class="collapse" ng-submit="addProverb(prov)" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
`
and last but not least the `AngularJS` controller's `scope` : `$scope.addProverb = function(prov) {
  $http.post('php/addProverbs.php', prov).success(function(prov) {
   console.log(prov);
     });
 };`

Thanks!